# SQL DATEDIFF() and using in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datediff

I am subtracting two times using sql `DATEDIFF()` (return type: int) function and using that value (in minutes) in asp.net application. If minutes are greater than 30 then it should be in red. But i am getting an error of "input string was not in correct format."

SQL `DATEDIFF()` function

```
Update lunTime
set lunTot =  DATEDIFF(minute, lunIn, LunOut) from lunTime
```

now using that value in gridview..

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    int lunTot = Convert.ToInt16(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
    if (lunTot > 30)
    {
        e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems e.Row.Cells[4].Text returns NULL or invalid value. additionally the query is a little weird, what does "from lunTime" mean at the end of your Update query ?

Comment: lunIn = start time, lunOut = end time, lunTot = lunOut-lunIn from table 'lunTime'

Answer (score 0):

Check for null value .Beside this there is nothing wrong in your code.

```
 int? lunDateTotl = Int32.TryParse(stringVal, out tempVal) ? tempVal : (int?)null;
 if (DBNull.Value != lunDateTotl)
 {
     lunDateTotl = Convert.ToInt16(e.Row.Cells[4].Text);

 }
 if (lunDateTotl > 30)
 {
     e.Row.ForeColor = Color.Red;
 }
```

Comment: Getting an error:  Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DBNull' and 'string'

Comment: Convert to int before compare with `DBNull.Value`. See update.

Comment: I tried doing it but getting same error as ealier.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can also highlight row by client script.

```
<asp:Label ID="lblUPSUserName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("lunTot") %>' CssClass='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("lunTot")) > 30 ? "__IsActive" : "" %>'></asp:Label>
```

and in script block

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $(".__IsActive").closest('tr').addClass("highLight");
    }
</script>
```

and put class in your style.css

```
<style type="text/css">
    .highLight td {
        background-color: green;
    }
</style>
```